# Using iBeacon to prompt users to download a specific app

Tags: ios, bluetooth, app-store, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon

I have read in a business newspaper the following use case for iBeacon :

> Clarks (US) - Prompting users to download their app as soon as they walk in-store

I saw nothing in terms of features that is dealing with such an opportunity, so I am quite confused.

On the other hand, the native AppStore application does support iBeacon (as seen in Apple Store to provide contextual services such as Genius Bar, etc). So it is technically possible that some sets of UUID x major x minor are used to invite users to discover an application with a specific store ID - and we still not will be at the OS level, but still at an application level.

So, what's the point ?

A future new release of iBeacon that is currently tested a kind of partnership between Apple and Clarks? Or am missing something ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the simplest explanation is that the reporter got it wrong.  The only reference to this I can find is [this Marketing Week article](http://m.marketingweek.co.uk/4009670.article?mobilesite=enabled),
Which says:

> Beacons examples
>   Clarks (US) - Prompting users to download their app as soon as they walk in-store

As you have suggested, this is not possible without another app already on the phone that does the iBeacon detecting.  While it is technically possible that the Apple store app could be helping do this, I think that does not sound at all like something Apple would agree to do.  It is more likely that some marketing network has embedded something that does this in a common library in popular free downloadable games.  This would only work for people have downloaded apps with this embedded library.

However, given that the claim of this article is dubious, and there is no available evidence to support it, I would be skeptical.

Comment: Hi David, we were dealing with the same article.
It looks like you are right at the moment, I will try to find further information in the day. Thanks